# Razor syntax parsing and compilation performance impact for different valid expression variants

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, roslyn

Given the following different valid expression variants, which one is the most correct and/or fastest to parse and compile?

Value assignment:

```
<TextBox Value=@myVariable></TextBox>
<TextBox Value="@myVariable"></TextBox>
<TextBox Value="@(myVariable)"></TextBox>
```

Complex value assignment:

```
<TextBox Value="@(myVariable.Summary)"></TextBox>
<TextBox Value="@myVariable.Summary"></TextBox>
<TextBox Value=@(myVariable.Summary)></TextBox>
```

Expression assignment:

```
<ValidationMessage For=@(() => context.Value.ValuePhoneNumber) />
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => context.Value.ValuePhoneNumber)" />
<ValidationMessage For="() => context.Value.ValuePhoneNumber" />
```

Comment: "most correct" might be a valid question. Speed of parsing is very irrelevant. And it's not parsed by Roslin here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Your comment is not very useful and also, parsing and compiling speed is important for large projects. Please remove your downvote, if it is yours.

Comment: Yes, when you have very, very many thosuands of these the difference in parsing could add up to several nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you fully understand the differences between a Razor component and a C# file, so apologies if I'm telling you something you already know.

Razor Components aren't classes and aren't strictly compiled by the C# compiler (Roslyn).  They're markup files using Razor syntax that get compiled into C# files by the Razor SDK as part of the compilation process.

To answer your question look at the C# code that gets built from the Razor markup.

The following Razor component (named */Pages/Test.razor*):

```
@page "/Test"
<TextBox Value=@myVariable></TextBox>
<TextBox Value="@myVariable"></TextBox>
<TextBox Value="@(myVariable)"></TextBox>
<TextBox Value="myVariable"></TextBox>
@code {

    string myVariable = "Hello World";
}
```

Gets pre-compiled into the following C# file before compilation.

```
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/test")]
    public partial class Inject : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
    {
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
        {
            __builder.OpenComponent<Blazor.Starter.Components.TextBox>(0);
            __builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.String>(
                 myVariable
            ));
            __builder.CloseComponent();
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(2, "\r\n");
            __builder.OpenComponent<Blazor.Starter.Components.TextBox>(3);
            __builder.AddAttribute(4, "Value", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.String>(
                 myVariable
            ));
            __builder.CloseComponent();
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(5, "\r\n");
            __builder.OpenComponent<Blazor.Starter.Components.TextBox>(6);
            __builder.AddAttribute(7, "Value", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<System.String>(
                  myVariable
            ));
            __builder.CloseComponent();
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(8, "\r\n");
            __builder.OpenComponent<Blazor.Starter.Components.TextBox>(9);
            __builder.AddAttribute(10, "Value", "myVariable");
            __builder.CloseComponent();
        }
    string myVariable = "Hello World";
    }
```

You can see this file at */obj/debug/Net5.0/Razor/Pages/Test.razor.g.cs*

So to answering your question, the first three all produce the same C# code, so no difference (and no compile time difference).  The fourth doesn't work as expected because Razor treats the variable name as a string.

I think it's simply a case of preference as to which of the first three you use.  The curly brackets are redundant with a single variable input.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. May you also comment on the parsing performance - I mean, is there any difference when using one or the other approach, when considering a large project and IntelliSense?

Comment: I can't see it making a difference, but as I haven't delved into the code I don't actually know.